# Can I trigger a journey from an automation?

Tags: journeybuilder, automationstudio

I think I know the answer to this, but I have an automation that runs daily and sends an email.  In this email the user can click on a certain link and if they do I want to trigger an email to send a week later. Am I asking too much of SFMC?  Could I build a journey via a script and run that daily?  I know I'm probably grasping, but I would just like confirmation it's not possible before telling the client.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods that you could use to accomplish this scenario. You could have a daily automation that queries the _click data view to find users who have clicked the link in the email and then injects them into a journey using a data extension [entry event](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_entry_events_data_extensions.htm&type=5).

Alternatively, for a more real-time solution, you could direct your link to a CloudPage that takes the subscriber's attributes and makes an API call to the [POST /interaction/v1/events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm) endpoint to inject them into your journey with an API entry event. After the user is injected then the page would redirect the user to URL you intended for the click to go.

If you are simply going to send out an email 7 days after an email click, and your journey contains no other activities, then it's probably just a better idea to have a daily automation that queries subscribers in the same manner as the first method I described, but then just sends the email from within the automation rather than injecting them in a journey.

Comment: Thanks!  I was over-complicating it apparently.